# Циклическая перезагрузка после обновления windows 10 (parallels desktop)

Tags: windows

Есть проблема, после установки обновления в виртуальной машине parallels desktop, постоянно перезагружается, есть ли какие-то ключи которые позволяют при загрузке войти в безопасный режим и откатить это обновление или просто сделать какие-то манипуляции с файловой системой, перекинуть данные с виртуалки.

Comment: а там, что нельзя с установочного iso загрузится?

Comment: @PavelGridin, а как?

Comment: @PavelGridin мне нужно сделать какие-то исправления в системе, что бы не было этой перезагрузки. Но я не знаю как.

Comment: А `F8` не пашет? Ну стандартный безопасный режим.

Comment: @donRumata нет не работает

Comment: Если у тебя не работает штатный аварийный функционал винды - значит либо ты убил виртуалку окончательно, либо использовал быдлосборку Васяна, либо parralels те ещё мудаки перехватывающие штатные хоткеи. Я склоняюсь к первым двум вариантам.

Comment: в win10 не работает F8, iso установочный iso скачивается с сайта microsoft, а загрузка с него обычно в настройках  вм задается, я просто не знаю этот parallels desktop, после загрузки можно запустить repair режим